# javascript change element size doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a javascript function that (onmouseover) would increase elements height and width by 10px (1px increase 10 times with setTimeout), but instead my element increases 200px in height and 100px in width. That doesn't make any sense. Example on how it's not working properly: www.modwebsolutions.com/test3/ My source code:

```
var el;

function changeSize(id) {

var elem=document.getElementById(id);

el=elem;

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    setTimeout(changeS,100);
}

}

function changeS() {
var tempHeight=el.offsetHeight;
var tempWidth=el.offsetWidth;
el.style.height=tempHeight + 1 +"px";
el.style.width=tempWidth + 1 + "px";
}


//    Update: tried
    el.style.height=(parseInt(tempHeight) + 1) +"px";
    el.style.width=(parseInt(tempWidth) + 1) + "px";
```

this time only adds 50px to height and still 100px to width... instead of 10px each way.

UPDATE: it seems that I'm gonna have to answer my own question, I'm still not sure, but I think it has to do with iterations running ahead of setTimeout and messing everything up. Unfortunately it seems that setTimeout can only work ok in recursive functions.

UPDATE2: recursive approach doesn't work as well... a total dead end.

Answer (score 1):

May be because tempWidth and tempHeight are trated as string you should try...

```
el.style.height= (parseInt(tempHeight) + 1) +"px";
el.style.width= (parseInt(tempWidth) + 1) + "px";
```

Comment: @Caballero: check for values in function. are you sure values are increasing this much value?

Comment: no the values are increasing too much, that's what creates the whole problem. I added "alert" after each iteration, width value always increases 10px instead of 1px. Height value increases 5px instead of 1px. This doesn't make any sense, the code is super primitive.

Comment: @Calallera: what's the initial value?

Comment: initial value is width:90px height:29px

Comment: the whole point is that it should have animative effect, anyway it seems that I solved the problem myself, read UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to:-

```
function changeS() {
var tempHeight=el.offsetHeight;
var tempWidth=el.offsetWidth;
el.style.height = (parseInt(tempHeight) + 1) +"px";
el.style.width = (parseInt(tempWidth) + 1) + "px";
}
```

Hope this helps because I feel offsetHeight will return `*px` which will result the style height to be `*pxpx` which will fail to render properly!

Cheers

Comment: P.S. offsetHeight and offsetWidth returns integer.

Answer (score 0):

From a similar problem,
Instead of
tempHeight + "px";
try
tempHeight + "pxpx";

Although it makes no sense and it's not documented, I found this to correct to the proper heights in IE10 as well as Firefox, Chrome and Opera using the style.height property. IE earlier versions not tested. It must be a data type problem.